# Writing to Excel using openpyxl results in a different character symbol

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Following is my code that is used to insert a row to excel

```
from openpyxl import Workbook  

wb = Workbook()  
sheet = wb.active  
i = ['an', '_xa100_list']
sheet.append(i)  
wb.save('appending_values.xlsx')
```

The problem is , after writing to the above `excel`, when I opened the file , i can see the second column's value as `'__ꄀlist__'` instead of `'_xa100_list'`.

`' \_xa100\_'` got internally substituted by `'__ꄀ__'`
.

why is it happening and how can i print the exact **string** to **excel** rather than this internal converted form?

Comment: This is happening because ```U+A100``` is the Unicode endpoint for the symbol ```ꄀ```. Unfortunately, it seems like openpyxl converts all strings to unicode before writing to a file, so ```str.encode``` doesn't seem to work either.
Maybe you can try checking out the [xlsxwriter library](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/) instead.

Comment: yes thanks it works with xlsxwriter . Under the hood ,  xlsxwriter escapes _XA100 by adding _X005F effectively making it _X005F_XA100 , thus Excel can render without any problem. But when the same file is opened in libreoffice, it shows 'X005F_XA100' as a whole . It seems libreoffice is not handling or considering _X005F as a escape seq.

Comment: openpyxl isn't doing anything special, the problem is you're embedding an XML escape value in a string.

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem. Otherwise, let me know in the comments what I can do to help.

Answer (score 3):

## Discussion

The box shows because you aren't using a font that has the [YI SYLLABLE DIT](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a100/index.htm) character. This is the unicode character encoded as `A100` in UTF-16. Now, why is Excel converting `_xa100_` to YI SYLLABLE DIT? It turns out that `_x[bytes]_` is an escape sequence in Excel. Give it a try with something that will render:

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook  

wb = Workbook()  
sheet = wb.active  
i = ['an', '_x0040_list']
sheet.append(i)  
wb.save('appending_values.xlsx')
```

You should see the table below in Excel. This is because `0040` is the encoded `@`.

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| an | @list |

## Solution

There exists a hacky workaround: escape the first character of the escape sequence `_`, `005F`.

```py
from openpyxl import Workbook  

wb = Workbook()  
sheet = wb.active  
i = ['an', '_x005f_xa100_list']
sheet.append(i)  
wb.save('appending_values.xlsx')
```

## More Background

This isn't unique to Excel, this is part of the design of [OOXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML), the underlying format of XLSX files. Here's a [bug report](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57008) from 2014 related to your issue. And the relevant part of the specification:

```
22.2.2.21 Properties (Application Specific File Properties)
This element specifies the application properties of a document. For properties of type string, NCR escape
format (_xHHHH_) is used for any invalid XML characters.
[Note: The W3C XML Schema definition of this element’s content model (CT_Properties) is located in §A.6.2. end
note]
```

Comment: Thanks, That worked. But can you explain more on what is the actual flow when writes happen to excel  from the user side,  like what sort of encoding or decoding happens inside excel internally to write the data to the file that a user sends though python or java or any inputs?
also if A100 is the unicode value that  i send, then '_x' wll just escape it and thus render them as the special character?
It would be helpful if i understand the general flow of how excel handles characters internaly

Comment: As mentioned in other comments on the question: Excel isn't doing anything here, the escape sequence is part of the specification for OOXML, the file format which Excel uses. This behavior is not the result of Excel doing anything further than parsing OOXML according to its specification. Also note that the trailing `_` is required in order to be a valid OOXML escape sequence.